# How to give a button more than one functionality - c# (Visual Studio)

Tags: c#, sorting, user-interface, listbox

So this is my first time using visual studio and c#. i'm making a simple task manager. I have a ListBox that displays all the current running processes. I want to make a button that will sort the ListBox in alphabetical order when i click it the first time, then reverse alphabetical order on the second click, and then back to unordered when i click it again.

So far i've made a button to sort the listbox like so...

```
private void sortButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  processListBox.Sorted = true;
}
```

This works, but how do i get it so that when i click the sort button again, it will sort it differently? I was thinking of some kind counter and sort it based on whether the number was odd or even, but i have 3 cases for this (Alphabetical, Reverse Alphabetical, and original unordered)

Thank you.

Comment: You could change the button text, and change your action based on that? Thats what i have done in the past for connect/disconnect buttons.

Answer (score 0):

The classic way to solve this is with a flag:

```
private bool sortDirection = false; //Or use an enum!

private void sortButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   sortDirection = !sortDirection;   
   if (sortDirection)
   {
       //Sort one way
   }
   else
   {
       Sort the other
   }
}
```

The answer to your more *general* question is similar, use a flag or enum. Alternatively, use a control that *includes* a flag like a `Checkbox` or `ToggleButton`. Then you can just go off of the `IsChecked` property.

To do more than two pieces of functionality, I would use an enum and the modulus operator:

```
private MyEnum sortType;

private void sortButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   sortType = (MyEnum)(++((int)sortType) % MyEnum.GetValues().Count());
   switch (sortType)
   {
   }
}
```

Note that you could cache the count value, and probably improve the casting code a few other ways.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Checkbox` instead with display type of `Button`. So add checkbox to form. then write these inside or behind `InitializeComponent`

```
this.checkbox1.ThreeState = true;
this.checkbox1.Appearance = System.Windows.Forms.Appearance.Button;
```

Voila now you have 3 state button.

Then you can switch like this (inside `CheckedChanged` event).

```
switch (checkbox1.CheckState)
{
    case CheckState.Unchecked: // original unordered
        break;
    case CheckState.Checked:   // Alphabetical 
        break;
    case CheckState.Indeterminate: // Reverse Alphabetical
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With your code I have an idea:

```
private void sortButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  processListBox.Sorted = !processListBox.Sorted;// true;
}
```

That sould work